# How to use single key shortcut in Windows Forms? If possible

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts, menuitem, menubar

I am trying to use single letters to navigate through the menu strip. I know that I can use `&` to show which letter I might click to represent each item.

But how do I actually set up single key shortcuts?

I was looking through the properties panel, but none of them seem to do this.

Oh wait, is that even possible? Or should I use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Key</kbd> to do this? Regular programs use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Key</kbd> combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding a key shortcut through the `&` character on a menu item, you can access the menu by typing <kbd>ALT + Key</kbd>

Comment: Ok, so there must be ALT combination. Fair enough.

Comment: Well, you could always detect any key typing and open a menu if the user click on `X` for example. But what if he wanted to type `x` in a textBox?

Comment: Very true. Ok that answers my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard behavior for a menu in Windows. If you show the menu, and your menu looks like:

```
 A
 B
 -
 C
 D
```

And you press D key, the action D will be executed.

If you are using the <kbd>ALT + key</kbd> functionality, you need to add & character on the menu item, as @Otiel said.

Comment: I believe what you mean is that when I press ALT+F to display content of File menu then I can press letter for example 'x' for Exit. Yes, I am aware of this.

Comment: @HelpNeeder: Yes, was that, so a unhelpful answer :-(

Comment: What if ***two*** (or more) menu items start with the ***same*** letter? I think you should cover that in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use code like this:

```
 this.InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(ApplicationCommands.Close, new KeyGesture(Key.C)));
```

This is a example for the application command "close". And it will be triggered by press the key "c". This code you have to write in the constuctor of the window or whatever because it only work on this way.

Comment: I like this answer. It might be useful one day. But for now I believe I will use ALT+Key combination.

Comment: thanks. yes it is better to use a combination with a modifier.